# Sencha Touch Store Complains that Model Does Not Exist

Tags: sencha-touch

I created a very simple model in Sencha Touch inside the model folder:

```
Ext.define('Vegetable',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',

    config:{
        fields:
        [
        {name:'title', type:'string'}
        ]
    }

});
```

When I try to refer to the model inside my Main.js file it says the model does not exist.

```
 items: [
            {
                xtype:'list',
                title:'Home',
                iconCls:'home',

                store:{

                    model:'**VegetableTreeSenchaTouch.model.Vegetable**',

                    proxy:{
                        type:'ajax',
                        url:'http://vegetablegardening.com/vegetable/catalog/23',
                        reader:{
                            type:'json',
                        }
                    },
                    autoLoad:true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

UPDATED: app.js

```
 views:['Main'],
    stores:['Vegetables'],
    models:['Vegetable'],
```

UPDATED: Vegetables (store)

```
Ext.define('VegetableTreeSenchaTouch.store.Vegetables',{
    extends:'Ext.data.Store',
    config:{
        model:'VegetableTreeSenchaTouch.model.Vegetable',
        data:[
        { title: 'Onion' },
        { title: 'Potato' }
        ]
    }

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why model:`'**VegetableTreeSenchaTouch.model.Vegetable**'` ???

Comment: I tried with Vegetable and still get the same issue. Is there something wrong with the model file. It complains that it has some typos??

Comment: Did you add the model in app.js
    `models: ['Vegetable']` ?

Comment: Yup! it is there (see updated question). The error message is that specified store is not found.

Comment: where is your `'Vegetables'` store defined?

Comment: Vegetables is inside the stores folder. I updated the source code to include stories in the original question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45136/discussion-between-darin-kolev-and-john-doe)

Answer (score 0):

Define the proxy in your store:

```
Ext.define('VegetableTreeSenchaTouch.store.Vegetables', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'VegetableTreeSenchaTouch.model.Vegetable',

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://vegetablegardening.com/vegetable/catalog/23',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
            }
        }
    },

    //...
});
```

and use an instance of the store:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    title: 'Home',
    iconCls: 'home',
    store: 'Vegetables'
}
```

Comment: Same problem the error on the console says that it is not able to recognize the Store called Vegetables.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your store and model with an extended name.

```
Ext.define('VegetableTreeSenchaTouch.model.Vegetable',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
```

and:

```
Ext.define('VegetableTreeSenchaTouch.store.Vegetables',{
extends:'Ext.data.Store',
config:{
    model:'VegetableTreeSenchaTouch.model.Vegetable',
    data:[
    { title: 'Onion' },
    { title: 'Potato' }
    ]
}

});
```

Not certain that this is the issue, but this is always how I name my models/stores to be sure they are referenced correctly.